# subtracting from average Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to calculate the average of a column from one table, then subtract the actual value from that average in another table.

The process compares the actual charged price minus the average of the price.

I get an error:  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

my query :

```
select proc_std_cost,adprc_pat_cost, 
(select round(avg(adprc_pat_cost),2) from adm_prc group by proc_code) as avgerage,
proc_std_cost-(select round(avg(adprc_pat_cost),0) from adm_prc group by proc_code) as difference
from procedure p join adm_prc a on (a.proc_code=p.proc_code);
```

if I change the query and remove the group by I get this result which I don't want. Because it shows the total average instead of average by group.

[image]

sample of the tables:

adm_prc

[image]

procedure

[image]

thanks

Comment: Please add table structure for both tables, along with sample data.

Comment: added..........

Comment: One way is to build a list using WITH (cte) and do the calculation after

Answer (score 0):

I guess that analytic form of the AVG function might help. Here's an example; I didn't feel like typing that much values (as you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data), but I hope you'll understand what it is all about. Pay attention to lines #20 and #21.

```
SQL> with adm_prc (proc_code, adprc_pat_cost) as
  2    (select 12055, 250    from dual union all
  3     select 43111, 355    from dual union all
  4     select 15510, 75     from dual union all
  5     select 19887, 68     from dual union all
  6     select 29844, 109.28 from dual union all
  7     select 33335, 70.45  from dual
  8    ),
  9  procedure (proc_code, proc_std_cost) as
 10    (select 12055, 250    from dual union all
 11     select 15509, 75     from dual union all
 12     select 15510, 75     from dual union all
 13     select 15511, 200    from dual union all
 14     select 17122, 500    from dual
 15    )
 16  select
 17    a.proc_code,
 18    a.adprc_pat_cost,
 19    p.proc_std_cost,
 20    round(avg(a.adprc_pat_cost) over (order by null), 2) avg_adm_cost,
 21    p.proc_std_cost - round(avg(a.adprc_pat_cost) over (order by null), 2) diff
 22  from adm_prc a left join procedure p on p.proc_code = a.proc_code;

 PROC_CODE ADPRC_PAT_COST PROC_STD_COST AVG_ADM_COST       DIFF
---------- -------------- ------------- ------------ ----------
     12055            250           250       154,62      95,38
     15510             75            75       154,62     -79,62
     29844         109,28                     154,62
     43111            355                     154,62
     19887             68                     154,62
     33335          70,45                     154,62

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```